# Magento multistore problem

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I followed [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/) to setup a multi store and got the following output.

```
There was no Home CMS page configured or found.
```

Comment: in  index.php file make `$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../includes/config.php';` `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../app/Mage.php';` `include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '../errors/503.php';` `require MAGENTO_ROOT . '../app/bootstrap.php';`

Comment: refer http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/

Comment: @AshishMadankar I updated my question

Comment: navigate to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages and set page for each website.